# How to set a variable to something inside an ID and a Class with javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this HTML code and I want to call the button with java script. It is for a 404 error page test I am making. The code is located in the body of the html and everything displays fine.

```html
<div class="contain" id="container">
        <div class="content" id="cont">
          <h2>404</h2>
          <h4>Opps! Page not found</h4>
          <p>The page you were looking for doesn't exist. You may have mistyped the adress or the page may            have moved</p>
          <a href="#">Back To Home</a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

However I do not know how to set a var (or let or const) to the button. I get errors when I try to get the id then get the class name then the button. I have even tried something like this.

```js
const buttons = document.getElementById("container").getElementById("cont").querySelector('a');
```

and it gives me an error because it sets the document.getElementById("container") = null;
I am new to HTML and Javascript so anything helps! Thank you

Comment: There's not much gain in nesting `getElementById`. Use simply `= document.querySelector("#cont a")`

Comment: If it is saying that that first id lookup is null, then that suggests that the element is not in the DOM at the time you do that expression.  Or you typoed the id in one of the two places

Comment: Always place your (not *Deferred*) `<script>` tags right **before the closing** `</body>` tag. 
A question still remains: what do you want to achieve with JS and that button?

Comment: PS: `buttons` is misleading. Should be `button` if you use `querySelector` (as opposed to `querySelectorAll`)

Answer (score 1):

can you use querySelector method :

```js
var data = document.querySelector("#container #cont a");

console.log(data.href);
```

```html
<div class="contain" id="container">
        <div class="content" id="cont">
          <h2>404</h2>
          <h4>Opps! Page not found</h4>
          <p>The page you were looking for doesn't exist. You may have mistyped the adress or the page may            have moved</p>
          <a href="#">Back To Home</a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your debugger. In the «inspector» tab, right click the target element, and choose «copy» «css selector».

This gives in this case: `#cont > a:nth-child(4)`

See screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICdgO.png

Then you can use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), like this:

```js
document.querySelector("#cont > a:nth-child(4)").textContent = "Modified by js!"
```

```html
<div class="contain" id="container">
        <div class="content" id="cont">
          <h2>404</h2>
          <h4>Opps! Page not found</h4>
          <p>The page you were looking for doesn't exist. You may have mistyped the adress or the page may            have moved</p>
          <a href="#">Back To Home</a>
    </div>
</div>
```